# unity/android alpha keystore signing (change to production keystore after Closed Alpha is already in the Play Console)

Tags: android, default, keystore, production

How can I change the keystore certificate after it was released into the closed Alpha?

I have a released version of the app in the Play console (released into the Closed Alpha) but it is signed with the android default keystore. 
Is it even possible to change the keystore to the production one at this point?

Please, help...

Answer (score 0):

Roma.

It is possible to create a new keystore in Unity, but it's not possible to upload that APK as update to an already existing one in Google Play, as it used the old key.

To lauch your app in Production, create a new keystore (keep it safe with the respective password with backups) and reupload your project.

Good luck :)

Comment: Already found a solution:I can see your app is enrolled into Google App Signing therefore, I’m happy to help you reset your upload key. I will however need authorization from the Account Owner in order to process this for you. Please ask the account owner of the Play Console to reply to this email to do this. 

The new upload key will be used to sign APKs that you upload to Play.